# Is there a method to find the plot graph data in a web page?

Tags: web-scraping, charts, highcharts

I'm not a web developer, so please bear me.

https://www.etoro.com/people/hyjbrighter/chart

I know that there are several libraries to plot graph in Javascript but how can I check if a specific page is using highchart or another competitor?

I expect to find some kind of Json in the source code but how can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to open the Network tab of Dev Tools, reload the page, and search for the piece of data that you want to scrape. Here I saw a number is 21361.15, I searched for it and detected the JSON file is from `https://www.etoro.com/sapi/userstats/CopySim/Username/hyjbrighter/OneYearAgo?callback=angular.callbacks._0&client_request_id=2ce991a6-0943-4111-abd3-6906ca92e45c`.
[image]

But you need to clear the parameters in this situation to actually get the proper information.
I don't know which language you use, if you use Python, here is the code:

```
import requests
import pandas
data = requests.get("https://www.etoro.com/sapi/userstats/CopySim/Username/hyjbrighter/OneYearAgo").json()['simulation']['oneYearAgo']['chart']
data = pandas.DataFrame(data)
print(data)
```

Output:
[image]
If you use R, use `jsonlite` package.