# Scraping data from a website which requires authentication [selenium not working], may I intercept chrome requests from .NET?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, webclient

I'm trying to monitor my portfolio on eToro.

While getting generic data is quite easy with the method provided by this answer
[Is there a method to find the plot graph data in a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66159329/is-there-a-method-to-find-the-plot-graph-data-in-a-web-page)

Getting the data specific to my user is more complicated. It seems they blocked selenium (I tried myself, but also many people here on SO faced the same issue).

The following request, made through Chrome, returns the data I'm looking for. I'd like to replicate the request or intercept it from chrome (as Fiddler normally does). But how? Is there a method to try?

```
:authority: www.etoro.com
:method: GET
:path: /api/logininfo/v1.1/logindata?client_request_id=*secretcode*&conditionIncludeDisplayableInstruments=false&conditionIncludeMarkets=false&conditionIncludeMetadata=false&conditionIncludeMirrorValidation=false
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accounttype: Real
authorization: *long secretcode*
cache-control: no-cache
cookie: **; G_ENABLED_IDPS=google; etoroHPRedirect=1; __cfruid=***; __cflb=***; ***; __cf_bm=****; ***=***; TMIS2=****
pragma: no-cache
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
x-csrf-token: *secretcode*
x-sts-autologin: true
x-sts-clienttime: 2021-02-15T12:18:03
```

The data returned:
[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66165935/196210